# How can I assign a variable from a string inside a json dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays

This is my get output on each asset im getting data back from

[image]

I can access the dictionary values easily,

```
page = json_response["page"].get("number", 0)
```

but how doo i access the value of the array, i want to be able to add up each critical vulnerability

this is the return, im trying to get critical, moderate, severe values from the vulnerabilities sub array

```
{'links': [{}],
 'page': {'number': 6, 'size': 10, 'totalPages': 13, 'totalResources': 123},
 'resources': [{'addresses': [],
                'assessedForPolicies': False,
                'assessedForVulnerabilities': True,
                'configurations': [],
                'databases': [],
                'files': [],
                'history': [],
                'hostName': 'corporate-workstation-1102DC.acme.com',
                'hostNames': [],
                'id': 282,
                'ids': [],
                'ip': '182.34.74.202',
                'links': [],
                'mac': 'AB:12:CD:34:EF:56',
                'os': 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition SP1',
                'osFingerprint': {},
                'rawRiskScore': 31214.3,
                'riskScore': 37457.16,
                'services': [],
                'software': [],
                'type': '',
                'userGroups': [],
                'users': [],
                'vulnerabilities': {'critical': 16,
                                    'exploits': 4,
                                    'malwareKits': 0,
                                    'moderate': 3,
                                    'severe': 76,
                                    'total': 95}}]}
```

Comment: Posting images of text, and especially links to image of text is not helpful.  Copy/paste the *actual* text.

Comment: What does "the value of the ray" mean? I don't see anything in the screenshot that says "ray". Please read [ask], and show data [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Do not try to use `**` to highlight code within a code block - it doesn't work. Show code in code blocks that *someone else can copy and paste, without changing anything*, to see the *exact* problem *immediately*. Please also read [mre].

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, i updated!

Comment: Break this up into smaller pieces. If I were solving this, the first thing I would do is get the `'resources'` list into its own variable. Then I would figure out how to get just the `"vulnerabilities"` from that list into another variable. Then I would figure out how to sum up the vulnerabilities. Don't try to do this all at once. Figure out each thing one step at a time.

Comment: what documentation shows how to get an array inside a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done a poor job of explaining it, but I'd bet that `resources` is a list of *multiple* dictionaries in your original data, and you want to do something with all of those values.

```py
vulnerabilities = []
resources = json_response['resources']
for d in resources:
    if 'vulnerabilities' in d:
        vulnerabilities.append(d['vulnerabilities'])

print(vulnerabilities)
print(sum(x.get('critical', 0) for x in vulnerabilities))
print(sum(x.get('severe', 0) for x in vulnerabilities))
```

Output:

```py
[{'critical': 16, 'exploits': 4, 'malwareKits': 0, 'moderate': 3, 'severe': 76, 'total': 95}]
16
76
```

Comment: yes sorry i could have done a better job :(

Comment: so this is my best solution, however its returning a post request and its not getting new variables from the next page response, since i have over 20,000 assets, what im trying to do is add up each response to a master variable that has total critical/sever/moderate

Comment: You should be able to put the `vulnerabilities` list higher up, and append *all* responses' vulnerabilities to it.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by higher up?

Answer (score 0):

You can read `vulnerabilities` like this,

```
json.loads(json_response)['resources'][0]['vulnerabilities']['critical']

# Out
16
```

Comment: im trying to acceess vulnerabilities, i can already access page number

Comment: if i do     json.loads(json1)['resources']['vulnerabilities']
i get TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: i am getting this error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
id really like to be able to assign a variable to the value, ie criticalvuln variable would be equal to 16

Comment: @FloydLee Read answer carefully. `json.loads(json1)['resources'][0]['vulnerabilities']`, you missed `[0]` after `['resources']`.

Comment: no, its an array, its not a dictionary valuue, its an array in the dictionary, keep getting error, https://help.rapid7.com/insightvm/en-us/api/integrations.html#operation/searchIntegrationVulnerabilities

Comment: so it works with     critical_vuln = json_response['resources'][0]['vulnerabilities']['critical'] because im assigning json_response = response.json() howeever when it goes to my next page the variablee doesnt change (the next get reequest), how can i do a for each

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull the value the way you know how instead of using json try:

```
crit_value = json_response["resources"][0]["vulnerabilities"].get("critical", 16)
```

Comment: theres an array inside theree, i have the [0], https://help.rapid7.com/insightvm/en-us/api/integrations.html#operation/searchIntegrationVulnerabilities  JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict